# Python Pandas replace all values if index is larger than a date

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for some help on a pandas data frame.

I have a data frame with the following structure

```
Date(indexed)      Total Clients   Sales Headcount    Total Products
2019-11-01         1005            5                  4
2019-12-01         1033            5                  5
2020-01-01         1045            10                 6
2020-02-01         1124            10                 10
2020-03-01         1199            10                 11
```

How can I fill in the column total products with 0's if the date is after 2020-01-01?

Expected outcome:

```
Date(indexed)      Total Clients   Sales Headcount    Total Products
2019-11-01         1005            5                  4
2019-12-01         1033            5                  5
2020-01-01         1045            10                 6
2020-02-01         1124            10                 0
2020-03-01         1199            10                 0
```

Comment: using .loc and assign it back

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your date column contains timestamps.

```
# Assuming `Date(indexed)` means that this column is the index of the dataframe.
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then use `.loc` to set all values from and including 2020 to zero.

```
df.loc['2020':, 'Total Products'] = 0

>>> df
            Total Clients  Sales Headcount  Total Products
Date                                                      
2019-11-01           1005                5               4
2019-12-01           1033                5               5
2020-01-01           1045               10               0
2020-02-01           1124               10               0
2020-03-01           1199               10               0
```

Comment: Thank you! I did mean that is an indexed column. 
If I wanted to use your logic for everything larger than "2020-01-01" set that column equal to 0. How do I do that?

Comment: `df.loc['2020':, :] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

using `.loc` to assign values based on a boolean.

```
# df['Date(indexed)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date(indexed)'])

df.loc[df['Date(indexed)'] > '2020-01-01','Total Products'] = 0
```

---

```
print(df)

  Date(indexed)  Total Clients  Sales Headcount  Total Products
0    2019-11-01           1005                5               4
1    2019-12-01           1033                5               5
2    2020-01-01           1045               10               6
3    2020-02-01           1124               10               0
4    2020-03-01           1199               10               0
```